# Ubuntu server doesn't automatically load bashrc config

Tags: server, bash, ecryptfs

I installed Ubuntu Server for the first time, and am having problems automatically loading my `/home/user/.bashrc` config. My home directory is encrypted with ecryptfs, which I think may have something to do with it.

When the server starts and I log in `/home/user` is encrypted, and I have to run `ecryptfs-mount-private` to see my files. `.bashrc` does not load, but if I run `source .bashrc` the config is loaded successfully.

If I want my shell config to take effect automatically, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, sorry I I've changed it now. It is .bashrc. I think the problem is that the home drive is encrypted when I first log on, and since the .bashrc is in my home directory it doesn't load.

Comment: I have the same setup, encrypted home dir (installation setup) on ubuntu-server, but i do not have to run `ecryptfs-mount-private` on first login, and my .bashrc gets executed. A simple test will be adding an echo to your `~/.bashrc` like `echo 'echo "DEBUG: .bashrc executed"' >> ~/.bashrc`to see if it gets executed on login.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I log in to the server for the first time, .bashrc is not run. However, if I mount the encrypted home drive, then log off and log back in again, .bashrc runs successfully. I think this indicates the problem relates to ecryptfs not mounting automatically. I'm going to try un-encrypting and re-encrypting to see if this results in behaviour similar to yours.

Comment: Sounds like your home really is not encrypted, just a single private folder in your home. What's the contents of /home/.ecryptfs ? And /home/<your_user> (maybe different when not logged in)? Maybe even echo $HOME to see where bash is looking